# Difficult couchdb query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, couchrest

I have the following query:

```
view.reduce.group_level(5).keys
```

which returns:

```
[["1f9c79a33f399a7937d880c5f31e8dbc", 2011, 12, 29, 13], ["1f9c79a33f399a7937d880c5f31e8dbc", 2011, 12, 29, 14], ["c38332ffc275b6c70bcf06ffc39ddbdd", 2011, 12, 29, 13], ["c38332ffc275b6c70bcf06ffc39ddbdd", 2011, 12, 29, 14]]
```

The first key is an id and the other keys are year, month, day, hour

I would like all the rows between 2010 and 2013. So I want to ignore the first key.

The problem is that i need to set the first parameter to get the results but i want to get all the results for all the keys.

for example: `view.reduce.group_level(5).startkey(["every_possible_key", 2010]).endkey(['every_possible_key", 2013, {}])`

If i leave the first key blank than i get nothing. If i give it "\u9999" than i get everything and it ignores the 2nd key.

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

map:

```
function(d) {
    if (d['type'] == 'State' && d['driver_id'] && d['name'] && d['created_at']) {
      var dt = new Date(d.created_at);
      emit([d.driver_id, dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth() + 1, dt.getDate(), dt.getHours()], d.name);
    }
  }
```

reduce:

```
function(k,v,r) {
    var result = {
      'hire': 0, 'hired': 0, 'arrived': 0, 'pick up': 0, 'drop off': 0,
      'missed': 0, 'rider cancel': 0, 'driver cancel': 0, 'no show': 0,
      'avail': 0, 'unavail': 0, 'other': 0
    };
    if (r) {
      var row = null;
      for (i in v) {
        row = v[i];
        for (j in row) {
          result[j] += row[j];
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (i in v) {
        if (result[v[i]] != null) {
          result[v[i]] += 1;
        } else {
          result['other'] += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're "doing wrong" is to use a key you don't need in your query as the first key of your view.

If you need it for another query, create another view.

Comment: But I want it grouped with the id. I just want more ids in the result.

Comment: If CouchDB hasn't been updated, the short answer is that you *cannot* have multiple ranges. Nevertheless, there are different ways to implement workarounds (the easier one being to put your "ID" as the last key). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991598/problem-with-two-key-ranges-in-couchdb or ask your question to CouchDB users list.

Comment: Ok thank you! Just not possible with just Couchdb. Have to find another solution with a search engine. Thanks!