# CouchDb get data from multiple key and date range

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

On my CouchDB DB, I have created a view with key ["userId", "startdate"]

I must get data from different userId and a range date. I have tried some of solutions, example :

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "startkey": ["userID_A","2014-05-02"],
            "endkey": ["userID_A", "2015-05-02",{}]
            ]
        },
        {
            "startkey": ["userID_B","2014-05-02"],
            "endkey": ["userID_B","2015-05-02",{}]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't work...

This [website](http://jamietalbot.com/2010/03/24/using-multiple-start-and-end-keys-for-couchdb-views/) is useful, and give a good example : (here to recup all posts of a category A or B in March 2010 -> June 2010

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "startkey": ["Category A","2010","03"],
            "endkey": ["Category A","2010","06",{}]
        },
        {
            "startkey": ["Category B","2010","03"],
            "endkey": ["Category B","2010","06",{}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Some have any idea?

Note : I need perform that in Java, with Ektorp. If someone has already do that...

EDIT : I think that my post is a duplicate. Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468684/multiple-key-ranges-as-parameters-to-a-couchdb-view).